# Dual Mobile Broadband Load Balancing VPN Router

Tags: vpn, mobile-broadband, load-balancer

I'm looking into the possibility of setting up a a connection for mobile video streaming.

- A laptop is hooked up to a router
- The router has two (or more) mobile broadband cards that tunnel traffic to a VPN appliance
- The VPN appliance reassembles the the 2+ connections into one transparently to the laptop

Does some system like this exist?